# show more content button only if more than 3 elements, else show nothing. Using jquery's :lt :gt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a code which almost does what I want. But I don't know how to modify it properly to tweak it's functionality.

Things I would like to do:

1. If there are more than 3 list items, hide rest of the items and show "Show all" button which reveals rest of the items when clicked.
2. If there are less than 2 items hide "Show all" button.
3. Optional - add a nice effect when revealing items.

**HTML**

```
<span class="show_button">Show all</span>
<ul class="test">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('ul.test li:gt(2)').hide();
if ( $('ul.test li:lt(2)') ) {
    $('.show_button').css('display', 'none');
}
else {
    $('.show_button').css('display', 'block');
}
$('.show_button').click(function() {
    $('ul.test li:gt(2)').show();
});
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't display "show more" button if more than 3 items are available, it just hides it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.test li:gt(2)').hide();

$('.show_button').click(function () {
    $('ul.test li:gt(2)').toggle('slide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BjG5M/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change only one line. Your first if-block always returns true. The `jQuery` selector always returns an object so checking against the result of it will always return true. The returned object contains an array of elements, which is empty (length of 0) if no elements have been matched by the selector.

```
if ( $('ul.test li:gt(2)').length > 0 ) {
    $('.show_button').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('.show_button').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, and example. Since I'm very new to javascript and jqeury I was wondering, why it didn't work.

Comment: @Uldis I had the block and none switched. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.test li:gt(2)').hide();

$('.show_button').click(function () {
    $('ul.test li:gt(2)').toggle('slide');
});
```